# Duplicate Class

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, unity-game-engine

Im integerating unity project to android studio project (flutter). Has anyone experience this issue?

> ```
> Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$3 found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> ```

```
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$4 found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$DecorView found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$ItemInfo found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$LayoutParams found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$MyAccessibilityDelegate found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$PageTransformer found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$PagerObserver found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState$1 found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SimpleOnPageChangeListener found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
 Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$ViewPositionComparator found in modules jetified-support-core-ui-25.1.0-runtime (:support-core-ui-25.1.0:) and viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error log 'ViewPager' class is found in two modules, so error will be gone if you were to remove `:support-core-ui-25.1.0:` or `androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0`.
now i am assuming that you have added `androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0` explicitly, so try to comment it first.